# How to convert concatenated time and date string into date?

Tags: android, date, simpledateformat

I want to set a notification for this I want to get the date and time. In my database I have saved alert time and alert date differently.

alert date format is:

```
SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy");
```

alert time format is:

```
SimpleDateFormat  df = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a");
```

Now I tried to concatenate the alert time string and alert date string and format it into date object but it is not getting format.

tried to convert into date:

```
public void setAlertTime() {
    try {
        Date date = new Date();

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");

        mAlertDateTime = mAlertDate + mAlertTime;

        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(mAlertDateTime);

        Log.d("AlertDate",String.valueOf(date));
        Toast.makeText(AddTaskActivity.this,String.valueOf(date),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    } catch (ParseException ex) {}
}
```

I am not getting date value. Tried to print date value in log also in toast but it doe not show anything. What's going wrong?

Comment: please post example data you try to pass in variables `mAlertDate` and  `mAlertTime`

Comment: alert date  22 Apr 2016  alert time  08:00  this is from log..@JordiCastilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change two things:

- add an space when concatenating date
- change your `SimpleDateFormat` (concatenating the `DateFormat`s with a **space** also):

```
String mAlertDate = "10 Mar 2016";
String mAlertTime = "8:00 PM";

String mAlertDateTime = mAlertDate + " " + mAlertTime;
//                                    ↑ space!!!

// date format concatenating other date formats
SimpleDateFormat  dft = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm a");
Date d = dft.parse(mAlertDateTime);

System.out.println(dft.format(d));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
10 mar 2016 08:00 AM
```

Answer (score 1):

for concatenate day if you merge the format then your format is

```
 SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm a");
```

Now Add the date and time with space so it is form of format like this

```
 mAlertDateTime = mAlertDate + " " +  mAlertTime;
```

now Parse it to format.

```
date = timeStampFormat.parse(mAlertDateTime);
```

define your convert format

```
 SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
```

and finally parse it.

```
 date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
```

## Note : the Upper thing I am giving Explanation.

#### Now Do Just this :

**Define this global :**

```
String mAlertDate = "4 May 2016";
String  mAlertTime = "01:30 PM";

Date date,date2;
```

and in try catch use write this code ,

```
try {

 SimpleDateFormat timeStampFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("d MMM yyyy HH:mm a");

             mAlertDateTime = mAlertDate + " " +  mAlertTime;
             date = timeStampFormat.parse(mAlertDateTime);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
            date2 = simpleDateFormat.parse(simpleDateFormat.format(date));

Toast.makeText(AddTaskActivity.this, date2.toString() ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


 } catch (ParseException ex) {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Change SimpleDateFormat parameters to fit the input.
2. Add a space between 'mAlertDate' and 'mAlertTime'.
3. Don't forget to set the locale.

   ```
   String mAlertDate = "10 Mar 2016";
   String mAlertTime = "08:00";

   Date date = new Date();

   SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm", Locale.ENGLISH);
   String mAlertDateTime = mAlertDate + " " + mAlertTime;
   try {
       date = simpleDateFormat.parse(mAlertDateTime);
   } catch (ParseException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(LectorPDF.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }

   System.out.println(date);
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding space between date and time

```
public void setAlertTime() {
    try {
        Date date = new Date();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzzz yyyy");
        mAlertDateTime = mAlertDate + " " + mAlertTime;
        date = simpleDateFormat.parse(mAlertDateTime);
        Log.d("AlertDate",String.valueOf(date));
        Toast.makeText(AddTaskActivity.this,String.valueOf(date),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } catch (ParseException ex) {}
}
```